# Transform not Working on IOS

Tags: ios, css, transform

So I am facing this little problem implement this code on iOS because I am not familiar how iOS works. I have this circle which I am using on my website and its working perfect on browsers and android devices but when it comes to iOS it breaks down and all of the degree's come to center. I'll be glad if someone could help me out on this one ..

The HTML

```
<div class='circle-container'>   
    <div class="center"> Center </div>
    <div class="deg90">1</div>
    <div class="deg315">2</div>
    <div class="deg0">3</div>
    <div class="deg110">4</div>
    <div class="deg135">5</div>
    <div class="deg180">6</div>
    <div class="deg225">7</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 15em;
    height: 14em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /*2.8em = 2em*1.4 (2em = half the width of a link with img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: dashed 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
.circle-container > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 4em; height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;

    text-align: center;
}

.circle-container div {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 4em; height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle-container img { display: block; width: 100%; height:320px; position:absolute; margin-left:-25px; margin-top:15px;}
.deg0 { transform: translate(5.2em); } /* 12em = half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5.4em) rotate(-45deg); }
.deg90 { transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(5em) rotate(90deg); }
.deg110 { transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5em) rotate(-45deg); }
.deg135 { transform: rotate(135deg) translate(5em) rotate(-135deg); }
.deg180 { transform: translate(-5em); }
.deg225 { transform: rotate(225deg) translate(5em) rotate(-225deg); }
.deg315 { transform: rotate(315deg) translate(5em) rotate(-315deg); }
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Post your code in your question

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I solved it on my own.

Comment: Please don't circumvent code requirements by putting non-code in code blocks. **Paste the code in the body of your question** and supply a link if it helps your question.

Comment: Yea, just did that. Thanks for the pointing out ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem, it was a silly one. I didn't use -webkit which is supported for `iOS`. Below is the solved `JS Fiddle` if anyone needs it ..

```
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 15em;
    height: 14em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /*2.8em = 2em*1.4 (2em = half the width of a link with img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: dashed 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
.circle-container > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 4em; height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;

    text-align: center;
}

.circle-container div {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 4em; height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle-container img { display: block; width: 100%; height:320px; position:absolute; margin-left:-25px; margin-top:15px;}
.deg0 { 
    transform: translate(5.2em); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(5.2em); 
    -ms-transform:  translate(5.2em);
} /* 12em = half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { 
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5.4em) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5.4em) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5.4em) rotate(-45deg); 
}
.deg90 { 
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(5em) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(5em) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(5em) rotate(90deg);
}
.deg110 { 
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5em) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5em) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5em) rotate(-45deg);
 }
.deg135 {
    transform: rotate(135deg) translate(5em) rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg) translate(5em) rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg) translate(5em) rotate(-135deg); 
}
.deg180 { 
    transform: translate(-5em); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-5em);
    -ms-transform: translate(-5em); 
}
.deg225 { 
    transform: rotate(225deg) translate(5em) rotate(-225deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg) translate(5em) rotate(-225deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(225deg) translate(5em) rotate(-225deg); 
}
.deg315 { 
    transform: rotate(315deg) translate(5em) rotate(-315deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg) translate(5em) rotate(-315deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(315deg) translate(5em) rotate(-315deg);
}
```

Comment: FYI it's best practice to place the non-prefixed version last. If not, for example, Chrome will use the `-webkit-` version even though it is no longer required. As prefixes are used when a property is still experimental, the final version and prefixed version may provide different results.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Is adding the `-moz-` and `-o-` necessary? Are they for firefox and opera, respectively?

Answer (score 59):

`iOS safari` still requires browser prefixes for `transform`

Duplicate all of your transforms and add a `-webkit-` prefixed version before

Example

```
.deg0 { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(5.2em);
    transform: translate(5.2em);
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/pcy5g7sx/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible issue here (when iOS seems to be ignoring a transform) is a bug in some versions of iOS where rotations that are an exact multiple of 90 degrees are ignored.

The solution that worked for me was to use a transform of 89.9 degrees instead (89.9 degrees worked as expected; 90 degrees produced no rotation at all). Not ideal, but in my case the difference wasn't noticeable.