# Absolute position of button centered but now full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fixed this issue before on a previous project but have totally forgotten how i resolved it so thought I would see if anyone knows of the top of their heads :)

I absolute position a button at the bottom of a container, and use left: 0 and right: 0 to center the button but then it makes it full width any ideas how to prevent this?

fiddle mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/

```css
ul li img {
  width: 500px;
}
.ty-subcategories__item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box {
  width: 58%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.left .ty-btn,
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.right .ty-btn {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f14fa1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/butterfly-sofa-bean-bags/" class="ty-subcategories-block__a">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/3/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?t=1437997789" alt="left" title="left">
      <div class="logo-box left"><span class="ty-btn ty-btn__primary">Shop Now</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `left:0` and `right:0`, you could consider using a CSS transform to center your button. For example, your declaration block might turn into:

```
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.left .ty-btn,
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.right .ty-btn {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #f14fa1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/1/). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**: Though, if you were hoping to get it centered in the black box (and not just the button's parent element), you'll need to update the width of the parent to something like:

```
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box {
    width: 161px;
}
```

(I assumed the black box is square.) Here's a new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/4/).

**EDIT 2**: To make the centering work responsively, we can do a little math: Assuming the black box is square, and the image width/height ratio are always the same, we can then calculate the percentage of the width of the image the box takes, with:

> 520 (height of image) / 1610 (width of image) * 100% = 32.3%

So this is the width needed for the parent of the button. To avoid text breaking to multiple lines in the button, you can specify the `white-space` property. So your CSS could become:

```
ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ty-subcategories__item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box {
    width: 32.3%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.left .ty-btn,
.ty-subcategories__item .logo-box.right .ty-btn {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #f14fa1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's another [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/8/). Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That doesn't center the button.

Comment: It centers it in its parent element. Do you mean in the black box? That's not the parent of the button.

Comment: Kind of of works, seems some of the buttons text break on to 2 lines for some reason... also how can i achive it if i want buttons to the right? as i see some buttons left and right. i split the CSS to use logo-box.left and logo-box.right

Comment: I used a % on the width as needs to be responsive btw, so need to avoid fixed widths really unless you know a better way to make it responsive.

Comment: Sorry try this one, i made the image responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/7/ if you resize you will see what i mean. need to ony center within that black box. and depending if set left or right depends on buttons container position. thanks for all your help btw!

Comment: All right, let me update the answer one more time to make it work responsively and avoid the button text breaking to the next line.

Comment: Thanks mate :) appreciate it!

Comment: Super! Glad I could help out.

Comment: Just checked on iphone and buttons are totally not where they should be lol resizing the browser is fine though.... just on actual devise its much further to the right. You think i need to adjust width maybe for mobile on the container?

Comment: Think maybe iphone does not like transform? dont see why to be honest. Do you have an iphone? i can send you the link to see what i mean.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one to test with...it's possible depending on the age of the phone that the browser it uses [doesn't support CSS3 2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). Is it an older phone?

Comment: Ahah, looks like iOS Safari [needs the `-webkit-` prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303339/transform-not-working-on-ios). Does [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t6Ljkjg/9/) behave better?

Comment: I do actually have this in my CSS: -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

Comment: Ahh i see i have translateY, i changed to translate and worked fine :) Thanks again for all your help mate. Really good of you! :)

Comment: You should be using `translate()`, not `translateY()`. =P (Actually, `translateX()` could work too, but it only takes one argument.) EDIT: Haha, you got it! No problem.