# SVG transform="rotate(x,x,x)" not working on iOS

Tags: ios, svg, rotation, css-transforms, gsap

I've created a Greensock animation with a circle that draws 90% and rotates so that text can be placed in the gap of the circle.  It works everywhere but on iOS devices. (see codepen below)

http://codepen.io/sumnercreations/pen/KgRJzZ

I know that iOS still requires the `-webkit` prefix, as stated in this question [Transform not Working on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303339/transform-not-working-on-ios), so I added that in the svg code, but it still doesn't work.

CSS Tricks says that this should work everywhere but I can't get it to work for me. https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

```
<!-- works everywhere -->
<rect x='65' y='65' width='150' height='80' transform='rotate(45)' />
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this on iOS devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greensock replied to my tweet and explained that iOS draws circles in the opposite direction and so one solution would be to use `<path>` instead of `<circle>`.  (they also mentioned that `MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath()` http://greensock.com/morphSVG`) could also do it.

They included a codepen that worked perfectly.
http://codepen.io/sumnercreations/pen/EgRovE

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is a bug in iOS that seems to ignore rotations by multiples of 90 degrees. I found it was fixable by simply using a value that was just fractionally off (eg. 89.9 degrees).

This might not have been the issue for you, but thought this would be worth posting here because it is one possible reason for rotations not working in iOS.