# transform: rotate(-90deg) not working on iPhone

Tags: css, animation, rotation, transform, css-transforms

I have this animated graph that I created, but the start of the path, for some reason, was at 90deg, so I put a transform: rotate(-90deg) on it to start from 0deg. This works fine on my desktop in Chrome and Safari, but when I view it on my iPhone, it seems to ignore my rotate and go back to its default 90deg starting point. I've tried a bunch of prefixes and nothing changes.

[Here's the link on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/WoomEd?editors=0100)

```css
body {
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.skills-graph {
 fill: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}


#javascript {
 visibility: visible;
  stroke: #ecf0f1;
  animation-name: javascript;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: ease;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
  stroke-dasharray: 880;
  stroke-dashoffset: 780;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes javascript {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 880;
    stroke: white;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #ecf0f1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 780;
  stroke: #ecf0f1;
  }
}

#html {
 visibility: visible;
 fill: transparent;
  stroke: #95a5a6;
  animation-name: html;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: ease;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
  stroke-dasharray: 691;
  stroke-dashoffset: 271;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes html {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 691;
    stroke: white;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #95a5a6;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 271;
  stroke: #95a5a6;
  }
}

#css {
 visibility: visible;
 fill: transparent;
  stroke: #3dd0ac;
  animation-name: css;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: ease;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
  stroke-dasharray: 502;
  stroke-dashoffset: 172;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes css {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 502;
    stroke: white;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #3dd0ac;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 172;
    stroke: #3dd0ac;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="skills-graph">
          <!-- JavaScript Graph -->
          <svg id="javascript" class="skills-graph" width="300" height="300">
            <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="140" stroke-width="20"/>
          </svg>
          <!-- HTML Graph -->
          <svg id="html" class="skills-graph" width="300" height="300">
            <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="110" stroke-width="20"/>
          </svg>
          <!-- CSS Graph -->
          <svg id="css" class="skills-graph" width="300" height="300">
            <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="80" stroke-width="20"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: I've tried to check your issue, but on my iphone everything is exactly the same as in the codepen snippet. Which version of iphone do you have?

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303339/transform-not-working-on-ios

Comment: @NatDavydova - I am using iPhone 5c. I seem to be able to rotate it to any angle except -90deg.. I even tried 270deg for full rotation but same problem. Also tried putting the 'transform: rotate' in the keyframes but still doesn't work.

Comment: @LizzyL - I tried all the prefixes.. no luck. I also was able to get it to work with -89deg, but I would rather it be a perfect -90deg. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but couldn't it be a problem with cache? Cause I've tried to check it on 5 and 6 iphone (and on other models using browserstack), but no such problem on any device

Comment: @NatDavydova How would I check that? I tried 'Clear History and Website Data' on my iPhone and reopened the codepen but nothing changed. Here's what it looks like on my screen:

https://twitter.com/mrseanbaines/status/799726852784979969

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CxkzUuMUcAA6HJn.jpg:large

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1855455/d040f527c44850696a18db53203cdf21

And this is my screen, iphone 5S. And while I was testing it on other versions, I'd got that result only

Comment: so it seems to me that you just need to clean all the cache and everything will be great

Comment: @NatDavydova Very strange! I just tried clearing cache again and no luck, but I will keep trying and I'll let you know if I succeed! Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: Hope everything will be ok! =)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the answer, but i played a little bit with the codepen snippet on my iPhone 6s (safari) and when i changed the "-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);" (in .skills-graph) to  "-webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);" it changes direction. Maybe you can find out the answer now yourself. (i'm not that good with code). Good luck!

EDIT: with "-webkit-transform: rotate(-89deg);" it seems right.