# CSS Marquee goes beyond the screen size on smaller devices

Tags: html, css

Have an unusual issue where by my css made marquee is going behind the size of smaller devices, there by extended the screen passed the containment div element size.

I've attached a picture for reference, I've checked all mobile devices and seems to have the issue there. the user can swipe to the right passed the screen size.

Picture showing the problem created by the marquee - https://i.ibb.co/7rkwJXJ/image.png

Essentially the right side of the vertical guide is passed the containment div size, there is nothing but white except for the marquee words moving left.

```css
.marquee {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.marquee-keywords-pink {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.marquee-keywords-pink span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee-keywords 30s linear infinite;
    color: #faa2b0 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-family: var(--heading-font-family);
    animation-delay: -14s;
}

.marquee-keywords-two span {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes marquee-keywords {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
<p class="marquee-keywords-pink">
<span>#Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example </span>
</p>
<p class="marquee-keywords-pink marquee-keywords-two">
<span>#Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example </span>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` to `.marquee` element. If are using absolute position to `.marquee-keywords-pink` you have to set and height like 40px to `.marquee`.

The `overflow: hidden` set on `.marquee-keywords-pink` is doing nothing as the element is expanding with its full width (eg 1400px). If you have an inner element with greater width, then it will cut it.

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.marquee-keywords-pink {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.marquee-keywords-pink span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee-keywords 30s linear infinite;
    color: #faa2b0 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-family: var(--heading-font-family);
    animation-delay: -14s;
}

.marquee-keywords-two span {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes marquee-keywords {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <p class="marquee-keywords-pink">
    <span>#Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example </span>
  </p>
  <p class="marquee-keywords-pink marquee-keywords-two">
    <span>#Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example #Example Example </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked for me, do you have an idea why this marquee isnt working on ios? for android it works perfectly, for ios it shows it 1 time then doesnt for 30s then repeats after 30s

Comment: I have not idea, you have to test it. The first that pops up in my mind is to use prefix - `-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);` in the keyframe. Check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303339/transform-not-working-on-ios)

Another thought is to use `translate3d(0, 0, 0)` with prefixes again, but this usually is helping for performance.

Comment: i added one for animation and transform, still didnt work

Comment: Can you create a codepen or a jsfiddle with the issue?

Comment: working perfectly fine on android and PC but ye only shows every 15 seconds in IOS. https://codepen.io/Newbie1122/pen/KKzxLQY

Comment: Cant really replicate the issue as it only shows on IOS

Comment: i am timing the issue on IOS, every 30 seconds it says the first span line then nothing then repeats after 30 seconds.

The writing finishes with in 5-6 seconds, so its way faster than PC and Android